# Is an email alias technically the same as a forwarding internally?

Tags: email-server, mail-forwarding

I know there are several drawbacks using email forwarders. So I was wondering if adding an alias to an address is the same as adding a forwarder to that email address? It just differs how tools like cPanel displays them?

Let's say john.doe@example.com is the actual email account.

Now I can add an alias like jd@example.com or joe@example.com.

Or I can create a separate mail account/address jd@example.com and instead of saving mails I can forward incoming emails directly to john.doe@example.com

Practically I prefer using alias, because bundling addresses that belong to each other makes it easier to manage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both an alias and a forward effectively do the same, they redirect mail for local recipients.

In the old days ***a "forward" was configured by the user*** by placing a `~/.forward` file in their home directory. Mail gets forwarded from a mailbox, with or without leaving copy of the forwarded message in the original mailbox.

In contrast ***an "alias" was configured by a server administrator*** in for example the systemwide `/etc/aliases` file. There is no actual mailbox for the alias address, any email received for an alias is going to be delivered to one or more other email recipients.

Control panels, sieve rules, virtual mailboxes and other innovations have blurred the lines considerably and I don't think most people really make the distinction on the span of control mentioned above.

At which step that redirect happens depends on the exact mail server and redirecting mechanism selected.
Postfix for example has several forms of address rewriting in addition to the `~/.forward` and `/etc/aliases` files  that all happen at different stages and will all have widely/subtly different effects:  http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

What exact method you choose may have impact om where other delivery steps such as anti-spam and antivirus filtering will happen, on the original address, on the destination mailbox, or both.

AFAIK The problem associated with redirecting mail messages is primarily when the target of that redirect is not on the same mail server, i.e. when you redirect messages for bob@example.com to bob@example.org